# pyplot barchart is plotted, but saved to empty file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a strange behaviour in my python code, where I plot a bar-chart and it will be showed in a window, but pressing the "save"-button does nothing and .savefig() creates an empty file with 0KB.

Even more strange, I have a for-loop before the barchart, which is creating several complicated plots and all of them are capable to be plotted and then saved, except the barchart, which is only plotted.

I do not receive any errors from the python-console.

This is my code from the plot-loop before the bar-chart:

```
for l in range(NumberOfResults):
plottitle=groupLimits[0][l+1]+' - Result Width and Probability Distribution of ' + str(numberCombinations) + ' possible Combinations'  
fig=plt.figure(plottitle,figsize=(GetSystemMetrics(0)/96,GetSystemMetrics(1)/96),dpi=96)
plt.clf()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ResultColumn=range(NumberOfInputs,NumberOfInputs+NumberOfResults)[l]
positions=range(len(groupResults))
#positions=list(map(int, np.array(groupLimits[1:])[:,0]))
#plt.grid(1)

y1=[]
x1=[]
for i in range(len(groupResults)):
    y1.append(groupResults[i][:,ResultColumn])
    x1.append([positions[i]]*len(groupResults[i]))
y=list(np.array(y1).flatten())
s=[]
for i in range(len(groupResults)):
    smin=min(groupResults[i][:,ProbabilityColumn])
    smax=max(groupResults[i][:,ProbabilityColumn])
    s.append((groupResults[i][:,ProbabilityColumn]-smin)/(smax-smin)*25000)
plt.scatter(x1,y1,s=s,marker='_',color='cyan',alpha=0.45)    

bp=plt.boxplot(y1, positions=positions, widths=0.5,
               labels=list(np.array(groupLimits[1:])[:,0]),
                patch_artist=True,whis=[0,100])

#plt.xlim(min(positions)*0.9,max(positions)*1.1)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=24)
ax.xaxis.grid(True,'major',color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.75)
ax.xaxis.grid(True,'minor',color='k', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.25)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(50));
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=24)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'major',color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.25)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'minor',color='k', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.25)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1)); 
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(int(min(y)),int(max(y))*1.1,0.5))


## change outline color, fill color and linewidth of the boxes
for box in bp['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set( color='blue', linewidth=3)
    # change fill color
    box.set( facecolor = 'None')

## change color and linewidth of the whiskers
for whisker in bp['whiskers']:
    whisker.set(color='blue', linewidth=3)

## change color and linewidth of the caps
for cap in bp['caps']:
    cap.set(color='blue', linewidth=3,alpha=0.8)

## change color and linewidth of the medians
for median in bp['medians']:
    median.set(color='magenta', linewidth=3)

y2=[]
x2=[]
for i in range(1,len(groupResults)+1):
    if groupLimits[i][l+1]=='-':
        pass
    else:
        y2.append(float(groupLimits[i][l+1]))
        if FailedCombinations[i-1][l] is None:
            failureString = 'No Results below the Limit'
        else:
            failureString= str(len(FailedCombinations[i-1][l]))+' failed @ ' + "{:.3g}".format(FailureProbability[i-1][l]*100) + '%'
        plt.text(positions[i-1],float(groupLimits[i][l+1])*0.9,
                 failureString,fontsize=18,horizontalalignment='center',
                 bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='black'))
        x2.append(positions[i-1])
plt.plot(x2,y2,marker='x',color='red', mew=4,ms=15,linestyle='None') 

blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Result width')
red_patch = mlines.Line2D([],[],marker='x',color='red', mew=4,ms=15,linestyle='None', label='Limit')
magenta_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='magenta', label='Median')
cyan_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='cyan', label='Probability of Result')
plt.legend(handles=[blue_patch, red_patch, magenta_patch, cyan_patch],
    loc='upper left',ncol=1,fontsize=24)


plt.title(plottitle,fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Engine Rotation Speed [rpm]',fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel('Absolute Pressure [bar]',fontsize=24)


labelsize = 24
rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = labelsize
rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = labelsize
plt.savefig(plottitle)   
plt.show()
```

In between I run some calculations to prepare data for the bar-chart plot. However, the code for the bar-chart is:

```
# Plot group-wise combined failures with all-combined failures at end 
plottitle = 'Failed combinations per group - and engine-all combined - TOTAL combinations: ' + str(len(groupResults[0]))
plt.figure(plottitle,figsize=(GetSystemMetrics(0)/96,GetSystemMetrics(1)/96),dpi=96)
plt.clf()
ax=plt.subplot(1,1,1)
y=[]
ind = np.arange(len(groupFailureProbabilities))
for i in range(len(groupFailures)):
    y.append(len(groupFailures[i]))
y=tuple(y)
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i]==0:
        pass
    else:
        string=str(y[i])+' failed @ ' + "{:.3g}".format(groupFailureProbabilities[i]*100)+' %'
        plt.text(ind[i],y[i]+100,
                 string,fontsize=18, horizontalalignment='center',
                 bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='black'))

width = 0.35
y=list(y)
plt.bar(ind, y, align='center', color='b')
labels=list(np.array(groupLimits[1:])[:,0])
labels.append('engine \n complete')
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(tuple(labels))
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=24)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'major',color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.25)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'minor',color='k', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.25)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(int(min(y)),int(max(y))*1.1,500))

plt.title(plottitle,fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Engine Rotation Speed [rpm]',fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel('Number of Failed Combinations',fontsize=24)
plt.savefig(plottitle)
plt.show()
```

What is the reason why I cannot save my bar-chart ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: It's kinda difficult to write the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem, if I have no idea why it happened in the first place.

Comment: A short code (minimal) is of course desired, but if you read closely it says "shortest code necessary to *reproduce* the problem"; emphasis on *reproduce*. Your code is simply not complete and verifiable, thus you won't get any answer here. The strategy in your case would be the *"Divide and conquer."* one from the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda difficult to write the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem, if I have no idea why it happened in the first place.

However, I managed to get it working with a rearrangement of the code lines:

```
plottitle = 'Failed combinations per group - TOTAL combinations ' + str(len(groupResults[0]))
plt.figure(plottitle,figsize=(GetSystemMetrics(0)/96,GetSystemMetrics(1)/96),dpi=96)
plt.clf()
ax=plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.bar(ind, y, align='center')
labels=list(np.array(groupLimits[1:])[:,0])
labels.append('engine \n complete')
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(tuple(labels))
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=24)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'major',color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.25)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'minor',color='k', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.25)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(int(min(y)),int(max(y))*1.1,500))
plt.title(plottitle,fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Engine Rotation Speed [rpm]',fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel('Number of Failed Combinations',fontsize=24)

plt.savefig(plottitle+'.png')
plt.show()
```